# Pycharm not showing inherited fields of base class in django 1.10

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using pycharm for my project, and I have created a core folder such that, it host all the abstract models, such that

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

When I try to import this class in other apps, Pycharm gave me an error, such that the base class attributes, such as models are not recoginzed

[image]

But this is perfect valid python code. How to fix this.

My project structue is [image]

Comment: Pycharm is correct, you aren't importing `models`?

Comment: so, you mean I need to explictly import models form `from django.db import models` even TimeStampedModel class has already imported models.

Comment: The file containing `TimeStampedModel` has imported `models`, but this script is a different file, with a different scope and context. Just like if you define a variable inside a function, that import only applies within the core package.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, I wish I could vote for your answer, but this is a comment, I understood, thank you.

Comment: @ManojGautam Glad to help! This stuff is tricky to get your head around, but gets a lot simpler eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Man you imported `TimeStampedModel`. But I didn't find your `models`. Where did you import? if your `models` inside `TimeStampedModel` then, import like that,

`from ..core.TimeStampedModel import models` or

`from ..core import TimeStampedModel.models as models`

Feel free to write pythonic code :)